# angular ng-repeat not working in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

This code works perfectly fine in IE but Firefox v28. I have two ng-repeat nested.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="rowAds in adsModel.Ads" class="row adrow">
    <div data-ng-repeat="ad in rowAds" class="col-md-3">
        <div >
            <strong>{{ad.Title}}</strong>                
            <br />
            <p>
                {{ad.Ad}}
            </p>
            <span>
                Publicado {{ getDateFromJson(ad.Activation) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy @ h:mma'}} 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <span class="label label-success">Ver</span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have other stuff above and below rendered using angularjs and twitter bootstrap everything works fine but the ng-repeat.

Comment: wow...just found the exact problem in my own application using Firefox 28..thanks to your post :s

Comment: In fact no! I was just clicking on an expected "empty result", so it works for me .. have you tried to use `ng-repeat` instead of `data-ng-repeat`
?

Comment: Ok. I fix it. The problem was "adrow" class in the first div. Declared like this div.adrow {
    padding-bottom:15px;
} for some reason Firefox doesn't like that in the ng-repeat this is using twitter bootstrap too.